# OSRM Distance Matrix

Tags: matrix, routes, openstreetmap, osrm

I would like OSRM to give me back a distance-matrix (just like ArcGIS' Network Analyst).

I notice that in the [documentation](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Server-api) this is obtained by a call to the able API. This works for a small number of locations (just like the example) however, when I supply a list of 1000 locations for a matrix of 1 million distances it cuts my HTTP request, e.g even this example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5001/table?loc=53.27528,-2.1271&loc=57.06322,-2.13991&loc=57.1913,-2.12272&loc=57.13205,-2.13559&loc=57.12008,-2.12476&loc=57.14234,-2.09557&loc=57.15555,-2.16155&loc=57.20477,-2.17626&loc=57.18151,-2.10008&loc=57.14901,-2.1&loc=57.15304,-2.13709&loc=57.14375,-2.1141&loc=57.14303,-2.11291&loc=57.14232,-2.11251&loc=57.13497,-2.12728&loc=57.14072,-2.12075&loc=57.12336,-2.13657&loc=57.12726,-2.11935&loc=57.14355,-2.10829&loc=57.13866,-2.09983&loc=57.13787,-2.08856&loc=57.13696,-2.0871&loc=57.10416,-2.08579&loc=57.06132,-2.12678&loc=57.06059,-2.12547
```

Is truncated to:

```
// http://127.0.0.1:5001/table?loc=53.27528,-2.1271&loc=57.06322,-2.13991&loc=57.1913,-2.12272&loc=57.13205,-2.13559&loc=57.12008,-2.12476&loc=57.14234,-2.09557&loc=57.15555,-2.16155&loc=57.20477,-2.17626&loc=57.18151,-2.10008&loc=57.14901,-2.1&loc=57.15304,-2.13709&loc=57.14375,-2.1141&loc=57.14303,-2.11291&loc=57.14232,-2.11251&loc=57.13497,-2.12728&loc=57.14072,-2.12075&loc=57.12336,-2.13657&loc=57.12726,-2.11935&loc=57.14355,-2.10829&loc=57.13866,-2.09983&loc=57.13787,-2.08856&loc=57.13696,-2.0871&loc=57.10416,-2
```

I wonder if there is an alternative way for me to send requests to the localhost server? Ideally I would like the same functionality as NA where I can give it a matrix of 50,000 by 50,000 locations and it churns through them in a day (with a cut-off of 20minutes) - would something like this be possible?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of libraries limit the length of the URL when doing HTTP requests. OSRM itself does not have a limitation in place on URL lengths. There is a `--max-table-locations` parameter that you need to update though.

That said for rather big requests I would suggest using our [node-bindings](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/node-osrm) or the C++ library [like in this example](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/tree/master/example).

EDIT: Updated link to example.